# What is the difference between 'estoy' and 'soy'?

Tags: gramática, cópulas

I thought that 'estoy' was the formal version of 'soy', but I saw that there were not many examples of using 'estoy' while referring to yourself. Also, I read that you don't use formal words when referring to yourself, only others. Is that true?

Thanks.

Comment: Hay, what do you mean that 'estoy' is the formal version of 'soy'?  I've never encountered that idea, and I'm wondering if it comes from a teacher, a book, a website, an observation?